# jQuery setting height in Firefox / Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

Iam having a problem with cross browser compatibility.
So there is a Website with a structure like this:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="left-collumn"></div>
    <div id="mid-collumn"></div>
</div>
```

I want to set the height of left-collumn to the height of content.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    setLeftHeight(content, left-collumn);
});

function setLeftHeight(elem, elem2) {
    var contentHeight = $(elem).height();
    $(elem2).height(contentHeight);
}
```

This works great in Google Chrome. But in Firefox the left-collumn gets a much bigger height than in Chrome. So when its for example 300px height in Chrome its mostly 600 - 900px in Firefox (Dont know why it varies)

Does someone have an Idea what causes the problem and how to fix it?

regards

Comment: Is there a reason you do not want to do this in CSS? Using javascript for UI purposes is not a good idea - what if someone has JS turned off?

Comment: I tried height:100%; in css but this doesnt work so well. I think every parent must also set to 100%? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Of course, the parent element also need to have  a height of 100%.

Comment: But than the parent element directly under the body has the height of the viewport and this is also too much if there is no content and too much whitespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using CSS in one of two ways:

1: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wd84Y/)

```
#content{
    display: table;
}
#left-collumn{
    background: #f00;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#mid-collumn{
    background: #ff0;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

2: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wd84Y/1/)

```
#content{
    overflow: hidden;
}
#left-collumn{
    background: #f00;
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
    float:left;
}
#mid-collumn{
    background: #ff0;
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
    float:left;
}
```